# Logging number of rows transfered using script task without using SSIS logging

Tags: c#, vb.net, ssis

I have over 40 independent data flow tasks inside a sequence container.

Is there a way to log to a flat file the number of rows transferred to the destination within each of the data flow tasks inside the sequence container?

I tried this method:

1. Store the rowcount value to a variable using a rowcount task.
2. Execute the destination table task.
3. Execute the script task to write the rowcount variable to a flat file after the data flow task.

This method worked, but I’ll have to keep adding script task for every dataflow task inside that container.

Is there a way to have this script execute automatically after each data flow task completes, to write the number of rows each dataflowtask transfers, with custom text saying "xyz data flow task transfered xxxx rows"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a master package, a "package handler package" and a child package per data flow.

First of all, in your master package, call the "package handler package" as many times as you have dataflows. For each, set a scoped variable that will have the package file path.

In the "package handler package", call a child package (using the parent package variable that holds the file path) that represent the dataflow and on success of the execute package task, call a script that will write down a variable that holds the number of rows in a file (or table, or wherever you want).

In each child packages, simply add a row count transformation to your package and write the value to the parent package variable.

So the sequence of packages looks like this :

```
               MasterPackage.dtsx
                 |             |
                 |             |
 PackageHandler.dtsx         PackageHandler.dtsx
        |                           |
        |                           |
 ChildPackage_1.dtsx         ChildPackage_2.dtsx
```

Note : There will be an error in your child package telling you that the parent package variable does not exists in this package, and it's all right. It will work at run-time.

Comment: As a side note, I use this technique in every of my projects to log package start, package end, row count, etc.

Comment: +1 to the general approach. Andy Leonard demonstrates a similar approach in his [Stairway to Integration Services](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/stairway/72494/) series. Well worth the read.

Comment: Thanks Dominic, being new to SSIS I wasn't sure how to configure Master Package and Package Handler packages. So what I ended up doing was using SSIS logging to write the log data into an XML format, and using another Script task in the end to parse through that log file and extracting the relevant data I needed and wrote a new simpler text file. It fulfilled my requirements and I was able to customize the text file as needed. And i didn't have to change the data task flows.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to keep adding the script task again and again, I would suggest creating a custom data flow component.

This would be a one time work but it can be reused again and again over variety of SSIS projects you may have.

Answer (score 0):

We use http://pragmaticworks.com/Products/BI-xPress - it takes the package and inserts the auditing framework which is configurable. Does cost a bit, but it's a good practice to evaluate what's available out there.